# Convergence of sum of $1/r^2_k$, where $r_k \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

If I have the following sum
$$
\sum_{k\geq1} \frac{1}{r^2_k},
$$
is it possible that this series converges? The sum of $1/n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ diverges but in my case it's about real numbers and not natural.

If $r_k$ grows very fast, then this sum will get small very fast, so is it correct to say that it will converge, i.e. $< \infty$?

Sorry for low effort question but I'm a bit lost. Any insight would be great, thanks.

---

EDIT: I'm reading a paper non-related to calculus but it has this sum and I think the author implies that this sum converges when $r_k \to \infty$ sufficiently fast. Is that correct way of thinking or it's wrong?

Comment: Set $a_k = 1/r^2_k$. This shows that you really consider $\sum a_k$  with $a_k > 0$. Conditions on the $r_k$ and the $a_k$ transform into each other.

Comment: Thanks. Can $\sum a_k$ converge? I mean, according to my edit if $a_k$ goes very small very fast, won't it converge? Sorry im a bit rusted on these parts of mathematics :(

Comment: Yes, of course $\sum a_k$ converges if $a_k \to 0$ "sufficiently fast". There are many sufficient conditions, e.g. the root test and the ratio test (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests).

Comment: Cool, thank you a lot for the link ;)

Answer (score 2):

It converges if $r_k >k$ for all $k$ because $\sum \frac  1 {k^{2}} <\infty$.

Comment: And even if $r_k>\sqrt k$.

Comment: No, that is not correct. $r_k=\sqrt {k \ln k}$ is a counter-example to your claim. @Bernard

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm reading a paper non-related to calculus but it has this sum I mentioned and I think the author implies that this sum converges when $r_k \to \infty$ sufficiently fast. Is that true?

Comment: You're  right. I should have said $\;r_k>k^\alpha$, with $\alpha >\frac12$.

Comment: @Bernard : Somehow I wondered if that was what you really meant. +1.

Comment: Or if there is $\alpha >1/2$ for which the set $\{k|\, r_k<k^\alpha\}$  is finite.